# asp.net - text boxes lose values entered on tab switch

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ajax telerik tabs in my code and when I switch the tabs my controls loses whatever I have typed.

I tried "enableViewState" to true. It didn't work either.

What I want is the controls to retain values entered on tab switch

```
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>

        <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" Width="100%" Align="Justify" >
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab PageViewID="RadPageView1" NavigateUrl="CreateNewUser.aspx?TabIndex=0" Text="Adviser Details" HoveredCssClass="hoveredTab" Font-Bold="true" />
                <telerik:RadTab PageViewID="RadPageView2" NavigateUrl="CreateNewUser.aspx?TabIndex=1" Text="Fee Split" HoveredCssClass="hoveredTab" Font-Bold="true" />
                <telerik:RadTab PageViewID="RadPageView3" NavigateUrl="CreateNewUser.aspx?TabIndex=2" Text="Signature" HoveredCssClass="hoveredTab" Font-Bold="true" />
                <telerik:RadTab PageViewID="RadPageView4" NavigateUrl="CreateNewUser.aspx?TabIndex=3" Text="Reference Details" HoveredCssClass="hoveredTab" Font-Bold="true" />            
             </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
        <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" Width="100%" RenderSelectedPageOnly="false">
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" Height="100%" CssClass="RadPageViewBorder">
                    <div style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; background-color: white;">
                        <uc1:AdvisorDetails ID="UCAdvisorDetails" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </telerik:RadPageView>
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" CssClass="RadPageViewBorder">
                    <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: white;">
                        <uc1:AdvisorFeeSplit runat="server" ID="UCAdvisorFeeSplit" />
                    </div>
                </telerik:RadPageView>
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView3" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" CssClass="RadPageViewBorder">
                    <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: white;">
                        <uc1:AdvisorSignature ID="UCAdvisorSignature" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </telerik:RadPageView>
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView4" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" CssClass="RadPageViewBorder">
                    <div style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: white;">
                        <uc1:AdvisorReferenceDetails runat="server" ID="UCAdvisorReferenceDetails" />
                    </div>
                </telerik:RadPageView>                     
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>


       <div class="col100" style="padding-top: 35px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">
             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>   
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" ValidationGroup="vgUser" runat="server" Width="120px" Text="Save" CssClass="btn-common" OnClick="btnAddUser_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteUser" ValidationGroup="vgUser" runat="server" Width="120px" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn-common" OnClick="btnDeleteUser_Click"/>
               </ContentTemplate>
               <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddUser"/>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDeleteUser"/>
               </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
       </div>


        <div class="col100">
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="litError" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <span class="successNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="litSuccess" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Can someone point out the issue pls ?

Comment: Did you check this- http://www.telerik.com/forums/change-does-not-persist-after-a-postback

Answer (score 0):

Your tabs have NavigateUrl property set, which means they render as links, which means they redirect, they do not use ajax.

That's why the values are not persisted.